# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory ember-cli-shims/app-shims.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to rebuild a project with updated packages but run into this error:

```
[folatt@ArkOS-Dev genesis]$ ember build
cleaning up...
Build failed.
The Broccoli Plugin: [SourceMapConcat: Concat: Vendor /assets/vendor.js] failed with:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-xZBOP47K.tmp/bower_components/ember-cli-shims/app-shims.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:583:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:490:33)
    at SourceMap.addFile (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:75:31)
    at /home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:200:16
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Concat.<anonymous> (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:198:24)
    at /home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:393:12
    at initializePromise (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:589:5)
    at new Promise (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1077:31)
    at SourceMap.end (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:380:10)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
    at Concat.Plugin (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:7:31)
    at new Concat (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:38:10)
    at module.exports (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/broccoli-concat/index.js:26:10)
    at EmberApp.concatFiles (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:392:10)
    at EmberApp._concatFiles (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:405:15)
    at EmberApp.javascript (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1297:12)
    at EmberApp.toArray (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1674:10)
    at EmberApp.toTree (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1696:30)
    at module.exports (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/ember-cli-build.js:89:14)
    at Class.setupBroccoliBuilder (/home/folatt/workspace/arkos/genesis/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:84:19)
```

I've tried running nombom to no avail.
I've also tried `bower install` and rerun `ember build`.

[Update]

I've noticed that in ember-cli/lib/broccoli/emeber-appjs contains the following line:

```
if (bowerEmberCliShims) {
  emberShims = this.bowerDirectory + '/ember-cli-shims/app-shims.js';
}
```

This does not correspond to the new location of this file which located at {package-root}/vendor/ember-cli-shims/app-shims.js

In other words, two directories up.

[Update]

As per request, below are my changes in package.json and bower.json.

As an added note, there's already a very similar project like this one that went from emberjs 1.x to 2.x, so I don't have to really worry about how to rewrite the rest of the code.

old package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.2.0",
    "broccoli-funnel": "^0.2.8",
    "ember-breadcrumbs": "0.1.9",
    "ember-cli": "1.13.13",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.5",
    "ember-cli-clipboard": "0.4.1",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.5.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-ember-uploader": "0.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.2.4",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth": "0.8.0",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-token": "0.7.3",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "1.13.15",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-resolver": "",
    "ember-websockets": "6.3.0",
    "mock-socket": "6.0.4",
    "semantic-ui-ember": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "websockets": "0.2.0"
  },
```

old bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "codemirror": "~5.6.0",
    "ember": "1.13.11",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.0.6",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.1",
    "ember-data": "1.13.15",
    "ember-load-initializers": "0.1.7",
    "ember-qunit": "0.4.16",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.20",
    "ember-simple-auth": "0.8.0",
    "ember-uploader": "0.3.2",
    "fira": "~0.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.4.0",
    "jquery": "1.11.3",
    "lightbox2": "~2.8.1",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.4.0",
    "moment": "~2.10.6",
    "qunit": "~1.20.0",
    "lato": "^0.3.0",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.4",
    "urijs": "^1.18.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.4.8"
  },
```

new package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "2.5.x",
    "broccoli-funnel": "1.0.x",
    "ember-cli": "^2.11.1",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "2.0.x",
    "ember-cli-autoprefixer": "0.6.x",
    "ember-cli-babel": "5.2.x",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.6.x",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "1.3.x",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "1.1.x",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "0.3.x",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "1.0.x",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.6.x",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "2.0.x",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "3.1.x",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.x",
    "ember-cli-selectize": "0.5.x",
    "ember-cli-sri": "2.1.x",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "1.2.x",
    "ember-data": "2.11.x",
    "ember-export-application-global": "1.1.x",
    "ember-load-initializers": "0.6.x",
    "ember-resolver": "2.1.x",
    "ember-simple-auth": "1.2.x",
    "ember-simple-auth-token": "2.1.x",
    "ember-uploader": "1.2.x",
    "ember-websockets": "6.3.x",
    "ember-welcome-page": "2.0.x",
    "loader.js": "4.2.x",
    "mock-socket": "5.0.x",
    "semantic-ui-ember": "2.0.x",
    "websockets": "0.2.x"
  },
```

new bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "codemirror": "5.24.x",
    "ember": "2.11.x",
    "ember-qunit-builds": "1.0.x",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.x",
    "fira": "git+https://github.com/Folatt/Fira#master",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.x",
    "jQuery-contextMenu": "2.4.x",
    "lato-font": "2.0.x",
    "loader.js": "4.0.x",
    "lightbox2": "git+https://github.com/Folatt/lightbox2#master",
    "moment": "2.15.x",
    "multiselect": "0.9.x",
    "qunit": "2.1.x",
    "selectize": "0.12.x",
    "semantic-ui": "2.2.x",
    "socket.io-client": "1.7.x",
    "urijs": "1.18.x"
  }
```

Comment: try bower install and then run ember build

Comment: Tried. No change.

Comment: what have you updated? show your `package.json` and your `bower.json`

Comment: try to remove the `bower_components` directory. In the new version the shims are loaded from `npm`, and maybe there is a confusion if the shims are still installed in the `bower_components` folder even if you don't have them in your `bower.json` anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using latest ember-cli version 2.11.1, You can see all differences here
[https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/compare/v2.4.0...v2.11.1](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/compare/v2.4.0...v2.11.1#diff-0a08a7565aba4405282251491979bb6b)

As you can see, they removed the below dependencies from bower to package.json, so you have to remove this from your bower.json

```
"ember": "2.11.x",
"ember-qunit-builds": "1.0.x",
"ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.x",
"loader.js": "4.0.x",
"qunit": "2.1.x",
"ember-cli-shims": "0.1.0", 
"ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.2",
"ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0"
```

And just ensure the below dependencies mentioned in package.json

```
"broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
"ember-ajax": "^2.4.1",
"ember-cli": "2.11.0",
"ember-cli-app-version": "^2.0.0",
"ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.7",
"ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.3.0",
"ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.1.1",
"ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.3",
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
"ember-cli-jshint": "^2.0.1",
"ember-cli-qunit": "^3.0.1",
"ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
"ember-cli-shims": "^1.0.2",
"ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
"ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.0",
"ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
"ember-data": "^2.11.0",
"ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.5",
"ember-load-initializers": "^0.6.0",
"ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
"ember-source": "^2.11.0",
"ember-welcome-page": "^2.0.2", //this is not required.
"loader.js": "^4.0.10"
```

For future [upgrading ember-cli](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases), consider the below step,

1.`rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp` -- Delete temporary development folders.

2.`npm install` --save-dev ember-cli@2.12.0-beta.2 -- Update project's package.json to use latest version.

3.`npm install` -- Reinstall NPM dependencies.

4.`bower install` -- Reinstall bower dependencies.

5.`ember init` -- This runs the new project blueprint on your projects directory. Please follow the prompts, and review all changes (tip: you can see a diff by pressing d). The most common source of upgrade pain is missing changes in this step.

Comment: Thanks. You beat myself by an hour.

Answer (score 0):

ember-cli-shims is no longer a bower package, but an npm package now and thus should be in the according dependency files.